# Java- Using a constant in an abstract class that needs to be used by subclasses as well

Tags: java, constants, abstract, final

I have an abstract class and 2 subclasses. There are 4 constants that relate to all the classes. I was going to place the finals in the abstract class but I understand a final variable is not inherited? 
Would I have to define the constant in every class (seems inefficient)? Or just make the constant an instant variable (doesn't sound like a good idea)?

What are ways I can go about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following would be available to all of your sub-classes if defined in the abstract class.

```
public static final Integer MYCONSTANT = 42;
```

or

```
static final Integer MYCONSTANT = 42;
```

or

```
protected static final Integer MYCONSTANT = 42;
```

The second one (package-private) is only available to classes within the same package. The third (protected) would be available to all sub-classes irrespective of their package.

Comment: I haven't tried but I'm certain that the second only holds if the child class is in the same package.

Comment: Then you should write it that way, the OP seems to be beginner and could be confused.

Answer (score 4):

Constants are inherited by childrens. You just have to make sure to have them `protected` or `public` so the children can access them.

```
abstract class A {
    protected final static String FOO = "bar";
}
class B extends A {
    somemethod() {
        System.out.println("foo: " + FOO);
    }
}
```

can be accessed from the class and all its children.

Comment: From what I've been told using protected is "lazy" programming and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @spaz: here we talk about visibility of constants - this is not really inheritence. You could also create a `Constants` class, so far I've seen it in all my projects. Btw: calling 'protected' visibility 'lazy' is questionable... it all depends on your needs.

Comment: @spaz that depends on the context. for a `final` variable that shall be accessible by its own class and its children its the perfect way of doing stuff. So... for real... why should bit be 'lazy' programming, anyway? And what should be used instead?

Comment: @home Yeah, but if your Constants `class` does nothing more than holing Constants that it would be even better to make it an `interface` (And yeah, Constants interfaces are great!)

Comment: Hey I hear ya. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: @Angelo: I agree, the problem I faced with 'constant interfaces' is that people start creating classes like `class X implements Constant` (I did this as well). I switched to final classes with private constructor defining those constants - believe me it's better :-)

Comment: @spaz If one of the answers solved you problem please mark it as correct (the hook on the left of the answers.)

Comment: @home If someone on my team do that I'd yell at them and have it removed. Bad coding is no excuse.

Comment: @Angelo: Again, I agree, but I've been in situations in which I had to take over code and suddenly found +50 classes implementing a `Constants` interface... so I changed my mind.

Comment: @Angelo: +1; damn, again I have to agree :-)

Comment: A constants class or interface is **usually** an anti-pattern.  Constants belong within their context, which in this case is the base class.

Comment: Adding more details to what @Robin has mentioned, [Discussion on Constants in Interface and Static import](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49572/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-an-interface-to-define-constants)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are. But as they are constant it should be `final and static` , `static modifier` make it there will be only one 'copy' and if this will be used only used in subclass only then u can use `protected` or if from other Classes too the must make it `public`.